# Cognito getId: NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Not a valid OpenId Connect identity token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to Cognito (JWT tokens & whole auth thing in general) so pardon me for asking stupid questions. I am trying to use Cognito user pools with identity pools. I logged in a user using the default URL (https://testapi123.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=<>&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://aws.amazon.com) and got a token. I am unable to figure out how to get the identity id from this token for use in getId() API. This I want to later use to get credentials from the federated identity pool (not sure if i have that part right either).

For reference, i have my code -

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
var params = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-2:<xxxxxx>', /* required */
    AccountId: 'xxxxxxx',
    Logins: {
        'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_xxxxx': '<**identityID???**>',
        }
    };

cognitoidentity.getId(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log('Error3 : ' + err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log('retval:' + JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
        var idenId = data.idenId;

        var params = {
            IdentityId: idenId,
            CustomRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/cc_admin',
            Logins: {
                'CognitoIdentity': 'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_xxxxxxx'
            }
        };

        cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });

    }
});
callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda 1');
};
```

The error - "2018-06-06T18:59:58.614Z   ce0fc216-69bb-11e8-bbfc-4fff0d953dd4    Error3 : NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token signature invalid. NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token signature invalid."

I have tried parsing the JWT token received (with jwt.io). It shows me some details but none of them seem to be identity id to be used in the request. I have also tried using the entire token as identity id.

Really need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, you only need to pass Identity Pool Id in params for getId function to work. It will return IdentityId associated with your identity pool. Replace

```
var params = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-2:<xxxxxx>', /* required */
    AccountId: 'xxxxxxx',
    Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_xxxxx': '<**identityID???**>',
    }
};
```

with

```
var params = {
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-2:<xxxxxx>'
}
```

Second, you can't create credentials unless you have idToken i.e JWT (JSON Web Token which is returned to client after successful authentication by user pool).

It looks like this..

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

You can get this token only by signing in...Run this command on terminal after configuring aws-cli or use aws-sdk and run function [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html)

```
aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id ap-south-1_xxxxxxx --client-id AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME="abc@123.com",PASSWORD="********"
```

Finally,Change your params function passing to getCRedentials method 'Logins' key to:

```
Logins: {
      "IdentityId": <result from getId>
      "cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/us-east-2_xxxxxxx": <your idToken>
}
```

Comment: The logins example was the missing piece for me. The AWS documents are so misleading and poor. Thank you!!!!!